# dateFormatter returns wrong date with two digit year specifier

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

I'm trying to parse date string from national Id string: "000101xxxxxxx".

```
func getDateOfBirth(from nationalId: String) -> Date? {
    if let substring = nationalId[0 ..< 6] {
        let dobString = String(substring)
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.dateFormat = "yyMMdd"
        formatter.twoDigitStartDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -100, to: Date())

        return formatter.date(from: dobString)
    }

    return nil
}
```

after that i convert this date to human readable format:

```
func printDate(_ date: Date) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM, yyyy"

    if let date = date {
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
if let dob = getDateOfBirth(from: "000101xxxxxxx") {
    printDate(dob)
}
```

i get the following log:
  `01 January, 12100` when i expect: `01 January, 2000`

Comment: Would be nice if you tell for which national id you're looking for.

Comment: Actually DateFormatter *has* a problem with 2000 as a two-digit year (depending on the time zone). The linked-to Q&A shows some workarounds.